# c#, .net, delegate, asynchronous callback. What am I doing wrong here?

Tags: c#, .net, delegates

Heres a little class for a button in a menu in a game.

I'd like to be able to pass a delegate method _triggerMethod when I'm instantiating each button. Then that delegate method will get called when that button instances trigger method is called.

I'm trying out delegates in C# for the first time here. And as far as I'm interpreting the documentation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173172%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) what I'm doing should work but visual studio is giving me a compile error in the Trigger method.

According to msdn article the code calling the delegate doesnt need to know about the original methods paramaters and such. What am I doing wrong?
Also in the msdn article they are only typing "Del" and that does not work for me. I must type "Delegate" which is odd.

```
class MenuItem
    {
        private Rectangle clickArea;
        private string displayText;
        private Vector2 _position;
        private Delegate _triggerMethod;

        public MenuItem(Vector2 pos,string txt,Delegate trig)
        {
            displayText = txt;
            _position = pos;
            _triggerMethod = trig;
        }

        public void Draw(SpriteBatch sb)
        {
        }

        public void Select()
        {
        }

        public void DeSelect()
        {
        }

        public void IsMouseOnMe()
        {
        }

        public void Trigger()
        {
            _triggerMethod();
        }
    }
```

Comment: "Method, delegate or event expected".. specifically here _triggerMethod();

Comment: also when I try and debug it I get

Comment: The name 'TriggerMethod' does not exist in the current context

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't created any delegate definition.

Example (from the MSDN-page you linked):

```
public delegate void Del(string message);
```

Then, you need to use that as your Type:

```
    ** snip **
    private Del _triggerMethod;

    public MenuItem(Vector2 pos,string txt,Del trig)
    {
        displayText = txt;
        _position = pos;
        _triggerMethod = trig;
    }
    ** snip **

    public void Trigger()
    {
        _triggerMethod("some message");
    }
```

You can pass references of the delegate around without actually knowing what arguments it expects (since it's just a normal reference), but when you want to invoke it, you do need to give it the correct parameters.

Answer (score 1):

You need to define the `Del` type if you want to use it:

```
public delegate void Del(string message);

public class MenuItem
{
    private Del _triggerMethod;
    public void Trigger()
    {
        _triggerMethod("Message");
    }
}
```

Note that you can use the built-in `Action<string>` delegate type instead of defining your own:

```
Action<string> _triggerMethod;
_triggerMethod("Message");
```

If you just use the `Delegate` type, you can invoke it using [`DynamicInvoke`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.delegate.dynamicinvoke.aspx):

```
public void Trigger()
{
    _triggerMethod.DynamicInvoke();
}
```